# Object ray visibility per camera

Tags: rendering, camera, visibility

I would like to be able to toggle the ray visibility of an object but only for specific camera's. This is because I have a room with multiple camera angles I wish to render, however there would be an object blocking the view in two of the camera angles. Sadly using frames is not an option due to it being an animation, though I tried using scenes and view layer but to no real success sadly.

[image: Blender's Visibility>Ray Visibility dropdown menu, a red arrow pointing at the unchecked Camera option which is desired to be changed.]

Comment: Did you consider using *Scenes* for your multiple shots (maybe *View Layers*, I'm not sure exactly) ? The checkbox you are pointing refers to the active camera, which there is at most one of.

Comment: I will look into it and see if scenes/view layers might be applicable for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a driver for that, but it is a bit hacky and you have to update the scene e.g. by python or moving the object so that Blender updates the driver.

[image]

[image]